# I keep getting a sementation fault when compiling and running my code

Tags: c

I know it means that there is a problem with trying to access restricted memory but I do not know how to find where the error is occurring or how I would go about fixing it. An small explanation would be very helpful.

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[1]) {
  char emptyBoard[3][3];
  char player;
  int row, column;  // moves
  int i, j;
  // int x = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      emptyBoard[i][j] = '.';
    }
  }
  /*
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
   printf("%c ", emptyBoard[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
  */

  FILE* filePtr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (filePtr == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open File \n");
    return 1;
  }

  while (fscanf(filePtr, "%c, %d, %d", &player, &row, &column) != EOF) {
    // moves = x++;

    emptyBoard[row][column] = player;

    printBoard(emptyBoard);
  }

  // printf("Total Moves: %d", moves );
  fclose(filePtr);
}

void printBoard() {
  int i, j;
  char array[3][3];
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      printf("%c ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a space to the start of the `fscanf` format string.

Comment: And familiarize yourself with `valgrind`. It will help you discover similar issues in the future :)

Comment: Please provide example content for the file to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You find where the error is occuring by using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

1. The program crash if row or column in input file is >= 3.
2. The fscanf condition is not sufficient to terminate the loop either check on number of records have been processed or add space so scanf eats the trailing newline:

```
    while (fscanf(filePtr, "%c, %d, %d ", &player, &row, &column)) != EOF) {
```

3. You call `printBoard(emptyBoard)` but it's defined as not taking any arguments, and you create a local `array`.  Try this instead:

```
void printBoard(size_t row, size_t column, char array[row][column]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            printf("%c ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

...
   printBoard(3, 3, emptyBoard);
```

4. This will result in players being accumulated.  If you want one player per board, then you need to either initialize the board or operate on a copy of empty board:

```
char board[3][3];
memcpy(board, emptyBoard, sizeof(emptyBoard);
board[row][column] = player;
printBoard(3, 3, board);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, if I want to have it so that the previous move is shown on the board would i still use the memcpy? The goal is to have each move from a file printed out. On the first printed board there is one move, the second board has the first and second move and so on. I'm not sure how I would do this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't what you asked for, but I noticed you're passing a variable to printBoard in printBoard(emptyBoard), but the function does not actually take any arguments. What will be printed here is a 'random' collection of values.

As for what you asked, do you pass any arguments to your executable? If it's titled 'run' for example, do you type `./run file.txt` or just `./run`? If you are doing the latter, that will cause a Segmentation fault because you are trying to load in a value that was not allocated to the argv. Allan is also correct, if the file you are loading calls higher row or column than 3, segmentation fault occurs because you are trying to access memory that you did not allocate to emptyBoard.

As to finding the cause of runtime errors, I have found placing print statements at the different steps of my program to be quite helpful. You could learn to use a debugger.